# For HTML attributes with only one possible value, can the value be omitted?

Tags: html

I'm working with some ancient web application that uses frames. There is an attribute of `<frame>` called `noresize`, whose value can only be specified as `"noresize"`. I've noticed in the code that `noresize` is not assigned a value:

```
<frame name="client_search_banner" src="pdc?page=client_search_banner.htm" noresize scrolling="no">
```

At first I thought that `noresize scrolling` was one attribute, but from everything I've read they appear to be two completely separate things. I'm wondering if the value is assumed in this case since there is only one possible value. Can someone please confirm?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These are called Boolean attributes. In XHTML, they must have a value, but in HTML, the value can be omitted. It also doesn't make a difference what the value is if it's there.

Answer (score 10):

In HTML 4.01 and earlier, [you can omit everything except the attribute value](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.3.4.2).

In XHTML, [you cannot omit anything](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#h-4.5).

In HTML 5 and newer, [you can omit everything except the attribute name](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#boolean-attributes).

Since the name and value are always the same for boolean attributes in HTML, the HTML 4 and 5 rules are effectively the same.

Answer (score 5):

noresize is a boolean attribute. When it's present, it's true, when it's not present, it's false. See the W3C docs for more details about noresize and other attributes.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/present/frames.html