# How to add attribute to html tag based on condition using loop

Tags: jsf, xhtml

I have a task to pre-select some entry from the `<select>` element, based on the current element of the collection that I'm iterating through.

We are using JSF to render html, and there is a loop that iterates through some collection. Based on the current item during iteration, I have to add or not add `selected` attribute to the `<option>` tag.

The problem is that `selected` doesn't take any value, it just have to be present in the tag so that the item is pre-selected in the `<select>` tag. I tried with `selected=true/false` but it didn't work. So this is what I tried and JSF returns parse exception:

```
<select value="#{...}">
    <c:forEach items="#{registrationManagementBean.offersMap}" var="entry" rowIndexVar="rowIndex">
        <option #{registrationManagementBean.offerId == entry.key? 'selected' : ''} value="#{entry.key}">#{entry.value}</option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

and that produces:

> Error Traced[line: 213] Element type "option" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".

When I try `selected = #{registrationManagementBean.offerId == entry.key? 'true' : 'false'}`, that renderes correctly, but it is not functional.

Is there a way to implement this need?

Answer (score 2):

The following is invalid in XML, and that is causing the error you're seeing:

```xml
<option selected>Value</option>
```

It should be:

```xml
<option selected="selected">Value</option>
```

That being said, it is strange to be rendering your own `select` elements when you are using JSF. Use JSF the way it is supposed to be used, and use a `h:selectOneMenu` to render a `select` element. With a JSF component, stuff like value binding and validation are easily configurable options.

See also:

- [How to populate options of h:selectOneMenu from database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6848970/how-to-populate-options-of-hselectonemenu-from-database)
- [For HTML attributes with only one possible value, can the value be omitted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23697069/for-html-attributes-with-only-one-possible-value-can-the-value-be-omitted)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So how could I pre-select some `<option>` entry using `h:selectOneMenu`?

Comment: Just set its value to the desired value.